# How to check which keys under ISD/CM are 'Secure Channel Base keys'?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I was digging out some issue and found that each ISD or CM has at-least one 'Secure Channel Base Key' that will be used to create secure channel session keys.

Now, my card has 2 sets of keys with versions 0x01 and 0x20(pre-loaded on card by issuer). Under each version there are 3 key identifiers with key type 0x80 (DES) and key length of 16 bytes.

So, during Initialize update command I specified P1(key version) as 0x01 and card provided error status word '69 85' (Conditions of use not satisfied) but when I specify the key version as 0x20, It works fine and required data is received.

Please help me to understand why my card respond with 0x20 key version and not with 0x01.

**Just for insight, ISD key information:**

```
E0 3A       
    C0 04   Id Ver Type     Len
            01 01   80      10
    C0 04
            02 01   80      10
    C0 04 
            03 01   80      10
    C0 04 
            01 20   80      10
    C0 04
            02 20   80      10
    C0 04 
            03 20   80      10
    C0 04 
            01 71   80      10      Type2   Len2    Key usage   Key access
    C0 0E 
            01 70   FFA1    0080    FFA0    0001    0181        0101
```

**I have two set of key version (0x01 & 0x20) and each key version and 3 set of keys.**

When I specify the P1 as 0x01:
**CMD:** 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 
**RSP:** 61 13 
**CMD:** 00 C0 00 00 13 
**RSP:** 6F 11 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 05 9F 65 02 01 00 90 00 
**CMD:** 80 50 01 00 08 AF 7B E0 42 A9 5E C2 30 00 
**RSP:** 69 85

When I specify the P1 as 20:
**CMD:**  00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 
**RSP:**  61 13 
**CMD:** 00 C0 00 00 13 
**RSP:** 6F 11 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 05 9F 65 02 01 00 90 00 
**CMD:** 80 50 20 00 08 AF 7B E0 42 A9 5E C2 30 00 
**RSP:** 61 1C 
**CMD:** 00 C0 00 00 1C 
**RSP:** 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA 20 02 1B 45 33 F6 23 28 3E 96 CF E4 3F E4 22 C0 F2 4F 90 00

Comment: Have you tried `P1 = 0x00` ? Have you checked your card manufacturer documentation if this card supports more than one active key?

Comment: Neither ISD nor CM are explained;  a reference to an explanation is also missing...

Comment: @guidot Do you mean what ISD and CM mean? ISD is Issuer Security Domain. CM is Card Manager.

Comment: ABHISHEK [01]

@PaulBastian The problem with P1=0x00 in initialize-update command is , we are giving authority to ISD to choose the key set to perform the authentication session. Though, when p1=0x00 ISD itself choose the key set 0x20. Which is clear to me that it is working fine.
My question is, If card has 2 set of keys both are of same type than why card doesn't authenticate with key set as 0x01.
Card manufacturer is not so friendly and their support doesn't answer so fast. 

Can we get to know which keys are used by ISD to authenticate (SCP02)?

Comment: ABHISHEK [02]
Any data or something that can point out the key version or something like this.
I am in very confused state here, I have gone through with GP specs and couldn't find any data for this. So, waiting for your expert reviews on it.

Comment: Can you provide all APDUs that were used to initialize a card to that state?

Comment: @PaulBastian Would you please specify the 'state' ?

Comment: The current state/status of the card

Comment: @PaulBastian
Current Authentiation Mode : PLAIN <br>
CMD : 80F2800200  <br>
Response : E314  <br>
4F08A000000003000000 - ISD AID  <br>
9F70020101 - Life Cycle State  <br>
C5039EFE80 - ISD Privledges  <br>

Comment: Where did the key sets with versions 0x01 and 0x20 come from? Did you load them yourself using `PUT KEY` or were they pre-loaded? If you loaded them yourself -- what exact command did you use (e.g. did you specify any key usage qualifier etc.)? Did keys with version 0x01 work before you loaded keys at version 0x20? Very strange is the status word "Conditions of use not satisfied" -- does this card support any other SCP protocol/feature besides SCP02 and (presumably) SCP10 which could use these 112-bit DES keys?

Comment: @vlp I have updated the question with required details. You have specified one point which is very important here i.e. 'key usage'. 
While creating new key-set in card to check whether new version of key created by me works or not, I did not find any parameter that supports 'key-usage' for key type as DES.
Would you please share any info on it? As it is crucial for me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I still don't see any PUTKEY or installation-related APDUs in the question. Did you understand our questions?